# Not getting JSON response when using HTTP INTERCEPTOR in Angular

Tags: json, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using **JWT Authentication** in my project and it is working well.

The issue I am facing is that before using **HTTP INTERCEPTOR** I was able to get a normal **JSON** response from the backend (**Spring Boot REST API**).

But, after using HTTP INTERCEPTOR **(for adding AUTHENTICATION header in all HTTP requests)** I am not getting JSON response, instead I am getting response as **[Object object]**.

**Most important**, the backend is giving response in JSON format, I checked it using postman.

**auth.interceptor.ts file**

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    //get token from auth service
    let token: any = this.authService.getToken();

    //check if guest user is a first time visitor
    if (!token) {
      alert('no token present');
      return next.handle(request.clone());
    }

    //add token and header to the request
    request = this.addTokenAndHeader(request, token);

    //return
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert('inside catch and pipe');
        //redirect to login page if error code 401 or 403
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          alert(err.status);
          this.authService.clear();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/access/login');
        }
        return throwError('Something went wrong.');
      })
    );
  }

  //add token to http request
  private addTokenAndHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    alert('inside add token and header method');
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
  }
```

**loader.interceptor.ts**

```
intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.loaderService.isLoading.next(false);
      })
    );
  }
```

**app.module.ts file**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NoInternetComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**user.service.ts** - where I am calling API URL. Here I was able to get normal JSON response. But, not getting after using HTTP INTERCEPTOR. Most important, the backend is giving response in JSON format, I checked it using postman.

```
getUserByPhone(phone: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http
        .get(this.constants.apiURL + '/user/get/phone/' + phone)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          alert('inside getuserbyphone method');
          alert(data);
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
  }
```

**Your help will be highly appreciated. Please come forward to help me in this case, if you have any information reagrding the same. Thanks in advance for solving my problem. Really appreciate it.**

Comment: Why are you wrapping an `Observable` with a `Promise`? Try to remove `return new Promise((resolve)` in your `user.service.ts` along with the associated `resolve` method then `console.log(data)` inside your `subscribe` method.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly I tried doing the same. But, unfortunately that is also not working. Still getting same response [Object object]

Comment: Do you by any chance have something like `console.log("Data" + data)` in your code?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly No don't have it.

Comment: Did you try to use DevTools and check your request within the Network tab? Does it return the desired result? Would you please share that?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Yes, I have checked that under the network tab and the response is available there. Also, tested the Rest URL using postman too, the response is available in the postman too. Should I share the headers (request and response) from the network tab ?

Comment: Yes, because if it works, then the `getUserByPhone` is being called correctly.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Yes you are right, I am able to get response in the "getUserByPhone" function but the problem is that the response is in [object object] state when I use JSON.stringify(response) then it shows the response but in string format but I want it in JSON format like angular does by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this , and one of those you already tried i.e using 'JSON.stringify'.Although this may not be a bad option considering interceptors will remain in place. But if you can't/don't want to  update your application code already written and just wanted to achieve this via interceptor then in that case I believe you need to update your interceptor code to format response data to a JSON format before consuming it in the application.

You should create a separate interceptor ( best practice and is completely optional if you want to do this in same interceptor) just to format the response. Since you have not share it , do you mind checking the typeof the [Object object] in the response, I assume it should be obviously HTTPResponse type.

By default , you should see response data in the 'body' key of the returned data. I have created a quick example and below are the snippet for the interceptor.

```
    import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    import { filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class FormatResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    
    
      intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
      ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
          return next.handle(request).pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
            map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => event.clone({ body: event.body }))
          );
        }
    }
```

so as you see the response if event.body and you can directly consume it in your application , as below :

```
import { SampleService } from './service/sample.service';
    
export interface CatInterface {
  fact: string | '',
  length: number | 0;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  apiData: CatInterface;

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService){}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.invokeAPI(); 
  }

  private invokeAPI(){
   
       this.sampleService.readData().subscribe({
         next: (res)=>{
           this.apiData = {...res};
         },
         error: (err)=>{},
         complete:()=>{console.log('Service Subscription Completed!');
        }
       })
  }
}
```

in the above code , I just deconstructed the response object.

So you should first need to check the response object structure and consume it accordingly.

For additional notes, here is my app.component.html code :

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<p><span style="background-color: yellow"> FACT from the API is : </span> <b> {{apiData?.fact}}</b></p>
<p> <span style="background-color: yellow">LENGTH from the API is : </span><b> {{apiData?.length}}</b></p>
```

and below is the screen shot for the output :

[image]

Hopefully this will help you to solve your problem. Please let me know by providing your feedback so that it will help others as well in future.

Comment: I tried code of `FormatResponseInterceptor` but getting error message:

`Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<HttpEvent<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpEvent<any>, HttpResponse<any>>'.

Type 'Observable<HttpEvent<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse<any>>'.

Type 'HttpEvent<any>' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse<any>'.
      Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse<any>': body, clone, headers, status, and 3 more.ts`


on line:
`filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse)`

Comment: @Avishkar - I think you are missing the imports of HttpResponse etc. 
Can you please check if you have included first line ( in my code ) from formatResponseIntercetor class?

Waiting for your feedback!

Comment: I have already imported the HttpResponse and other required imports. After that I started receiving this error.

Comment: can you share 'intercept' method code snippet from all Interceptors that you are using?

Comment: Yes, I have already shared both the interceptor codes in the question. Request you to please go through it once again. I have 2 interceptors. One if AuthInterceptor for adding 'Authentication' header in HTTP requests and second one if for showing loader only.

Comment: @Avishkar have you found the solutionto this error ?

Comment: @Fozix yes i resolved it myself.